# Deploying Rails application to MS Server 2012

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, windows-server

I've developed a local Rails application and it needs to be deployed to a Windows Server (only choice). I've got remote access to it and have put all of the application files over, but I cannot get this to run and to be accessible by other people.

I've tried using IIS but I'm getting error after error and not getting anywhere (I can browse through the files in the browser - about as far as I got).

Is there any other solutions where I can have it running on the server?

Comment: How about running Linux in a virtual machine?

Comment: Okay, you can run rails with bound to 0.0.0.0 -> it will be accessed directly.
I mean "rails s -p 80 -b 0.0.0.0", for example. Disable IIS for that moment.
Otherwise you can run at another port(3000, for example) and create Port Forwarding to that port(http://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server).